# i want to save both user and admin data on codeigniter session but i cant save both to user_data. so what can i do?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i created a site with admin area and user area using codeigniter. but both admin and user can't log in at same time. because the session user_data is only can use once. 
so how can i save another session data?

this is how i save admin data.

```
private function access_granted(){
        $admin_session_data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_admin_logged_in' => 1
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($admin_session_data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('successed', 'You Logged in Successfully');
        $this->login_failed_or_successed();
    }
```

Comment: U are differentiating between admin and user in your db right???

Comment: Are you want to log in to the admin and user at the same time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the user info and admin info to session as two separate arrays as,

```
$user_info=array(
'id'=>$id,
........
);
```

And

```
$admin_info=array(
'id'=>$id,
........
);


$this->session->set_userdata(array("users" => $user_info));
```

and

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array("admin" => $admin_info));
```

and unset this as,

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('users');

$this->session->unset_userdata('admin');
```

Comment: i want to check the id number in the session users.
so how can i do it 
ex: echo $this->session->userdata("id");

Comment: $user = $this->session->userdata('users');

Comment: now my code is like this in admin controller
private function access_granted(){
        $admin_session_data = array(
            'adminname' => $this->input->post('adminname'),
            'is_admin_logged_in' => 1
        );
        
        $this->session->set_userdata(array("admin" => $admin_session_data));
        $this->session->set_flashdata('successed', 'You Logged in Successfully');
        $this->login_failed_or_successed();
    }
but when i var_dump 
like this
var_dump($this->session->userdata('admin'))

array(2) { ["adminname"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin_logged_in"]=> int(1) }

Comment: it's ok it's ok. there is a little mistake

Comment: now it is like this
can you kindly tel me how to echo only the adminname from this thing
string(26) "You Logged in Successfully" array(2) { ["adminname"]=> string(14) "admin_password" ["is_admin_logged_in"]=> int(1) }

Comment: Use  $user = $this->session->userdata('users');  then use$id=$users['id'];